# mysql inner join giving bad results (?)

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, left-join, inner-join

The following sql call works fine, returns the correct total retail for customers:

```
SELECT  customer.id,
        customer.first_name, 
        customer.last_name,
        SUM(sales_line_item_detail.retail) AS total_retail
FROM sales_line_item_detail
    INNER JOIN sales_header 
        ON sales_header.id = sales_line_item_detail.sales_header_id
    INNER JOIN customer 
        ON customer.id = sales_header.customer_id
GROUP BY sales_header.customer_Id
ORDER BY total_Retail DESC
LIMIT 10
```

However, i need it to return the customers telephone and email addresses as well.. please keep in mind that not all customers have an email address and telephone number. whenever i left join the email and numbers tables, it throws the total_retail amount off by thousands and I am not sure why.

The following query gives completely wrong results for the total_retail field:

```
    SELECT  customer.id,
        customer.first_name, 
        customer.last_name,
        IF(
            ISNULL( gemstore.customer_phone_numbers.Number), 
            'No Number..', 
            gemstore.customer_phone_numbers.Number
            ) AS Number,
        IF(
            ISNULL(gemstore.customer_emails.Email), 
            'No Email...', 
            gemstore.customer_emails.Email
            ) AS Email,
        SUM(sales_line_item_detail.retail) AS total_retail,
FROM sales_line_item_detail
    INNER JOIN sales_header 
        ON sales_header.id = sales_line_item_detail.sales_header_id
    INNER JOIN customer 
        ON customer.id = sales_header.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN gemstore.customer_emails 
        ON gemstore.customer_emails.Customer_ID = gemstore.customer.ID
    LEFT JOIN gemstore.customer_phone_numbers 
        ON gemstore.customer_phone_numbers.Customer_ID = gemstore.customer.ID
GROUP BY sales_header.customer_Id
ORDER BY total_Retail DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Any help figuring out why it is throwing off my results is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that there are multiple records for a Customer_ID in either the customer_emails or customer_phone_numbers tables?

Comment: Yes - a customer can have from 1 - 100 emails or phone numbers in those two tables.

Comment: but they can also have 0 - thats why i did a left join with the if(isnull)

Comment: So the multiple records are throwing off your results. I think you are going to need to add a subquery to join to the phone table. I'm not sure of the MySql syntax but it should be something like this:   WHERE gemstore.customer.ID = (select max(phone_number) from customer_phone_numbers where customer_ID = gemstore.customer.ID )     and assuming it doesn't matter which phone_number is returned.

Comment: where customer.id = ( select max(number) from customer_phone_numbers where customer_phone_numbers.customer_id = customer.id ) errors - im goin gto have to mess around with that the only type of sub query i have ever done is a where id IN ( select id from table ) etc.

Comment: gemstore.customer_phone_numbers.Number = ( select MAX(number) from customer_phone_numbers WHERE customer_id = gemstore.customer.id and active = -1 order by default_num )

Comment: this gives me some correct results and some incorrect results (i took out all email joining )

Answer (score 1):

You'll be matching too many records. Try the query without the group by clause and you'll see which ones and how. Most likely the left join's will duplicate order rows on every customer email/phone match.

Comment: if i take the group by off, i get once result

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant to say take away the group by and the sum. So that you'll see the actual rows that are being used.

Comment: yes - it is showing me the same customer for each phone number or email they have in those two tables even with the left outer join --- i need to figure out how to return atleast one number or email however as it is for a report that needs the numbers and emails

Comment: use a subselect in stead of a join.

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure, as i can't test this, but the following might be happening.

If there are more than one email or phone number per customer the final result might get multiplied, because of the new joins.

Imagine the query without the group_by and join to sales:

```
CustomerId    Email          phoneNumber
1             test@gmx.com   0122233
1             mail@yahoo.com 0122233
```

The user in this example has 2 mailadresses.

If you would now add the join to sales and the group by, you would have doubled total_retail.

If this should be the case, replacing the LEFT JOIN with an LEFT OUTER JOIN should do the trick. In that case you will however only see the first email/phonenumer of the customer.

Comment: that is exactly what it is doing, doubling the total_Retail per how many phones / emails they have. i changed it to left outer join - but it is still doubling.